# How to read the lines of the input in arbitrary order?

Tags: fortran

I would like to ask how I can read the lines of the input in arbitrary order. In other words: how to read a given line of the input? I have written the next test program:

```
  program main
  implicit integer*4(i-n)
  dimension ind(6)
  do i=1,6
     ind(i)=6-i
  end do
  open(7,file='test.inp',status='old')
  do i=0,5
     call fseek(7,ind(i+1),0)
     read(7,*) m
     write(*,*) m
     call fseek(7,0,0)
  end do
  end
```

where test.inp contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

My output given is:

```
4
5
6
2
3
4
```

What is the problem? I would expect

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: `fseek` which is a gfortran extension, seems to not work properly with formated (text) files.  Note it is seeking to byte positions, not lines, but even given that its behavior would best be described as buggy an nonsensical if you mix `fseek` with formatted reads.

Answer (score 1):

for a text file the simplest thing is to just use an empty read to advance lines. This will read the `nth` line of file opened with  `unit=iu`

```
       rewind(iu)
       do i=1,n-1
       read(iu,*)
       enddo
       read(iu,*)data
```

Note if you are doing a bunch of reads from the same file you should consider reading the whole file into a character array, then you can very simply access lines by index.

here is an example of reading in a whole file:

```
  implicit none
  integer::iu=20,i,n,io
  character(len=:),allocatable::line(:)
  real::x,y
  open(iu,file='filename')
  n=0
  do while(.true.) ! pass through once to count the lines
     read(iu,*,iostat=io)
     if(io.ne.0)exit
     n=n+1
  enddo
  write(*,*)'lines in file=',n
  !allocate the character array. Here I'm hard coding a max line length
  !of 130 characters (that can be fixed if its a problem.)
  allocate(character(130)::line(n))      
  rewind(iu)
  !read in entire file
  do i=1,n 
     read(iu,'(a)')line(i)
  enddo
  !now we can random access the lines using internal reads:
  read(line(55),*)x,y
  ! ( obviously use whatever format you need on the read )
  write(*,*)x,y
  end
```

One obvious drawback to this is you can not read data that spans multiple lines the same as if you were reading from the file.

Edit: my old version of gfortran doensn't like that allocatable character syntax.
This works:

```
 character(len=130),allocatable::line(:)
  ...
 allocate(line(n))
```

Comment: Plus one can beckspace and rewind if necessary.